In what way exactly does a Dynkin diagram encode a type of geometrical incidence structure?
In his talk "Split Octonions and the Rolling Ball," John Baez says that a Dynkin diagram describes a type of geometry, with vertices representing types of objects, and edges representing incidence relations between them. The example he gives is of $A_3$, representing projective 3-space. The first vertex represents points, the second represents lines, and the third represents planes.
How does this fit in with the usual Lie theory picture of the correspondence with the diagrams, and how does this end up actually generalizing to the other diagrams? How can the types of geometry the other diagrams correspond to be described?

I'm not super familiar with this but the terms you want to look up are "parabolic subgroup" and "flag variety," see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_subgroup and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety for starters.
